# TYPO3 9 and Flux: Adding an element / section / container multiple times

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.26 and Flux 9.4.2 and I would like to create a calendar-element with exactly five elements/days. Each day needs some input fields. It would look something like this:

Calendar:

- Day 1: Offer ID, Image
- Day 2: Offer ID, Image
- Day 3: ...

Considering DRY, I would like to use some kind of for-loop, but this doesn't work. What I tried:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
 ...
    <f:for each="{0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4}" as="foo" key="number">
          <flux:field.multiRelation label="Angebot Tag 1" name="offerDay1" table="tx_data_domain_model_offer">
          </flux:field.multiRelation>
    </f:for>
```

If I enter five of the multiRelation-fields, it works as expected but as these subelements will get more input fields the code would get bloated.

I also tried using a flux [section](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/flux/9.0.1/Form/Section.html) but it seems like there is no option of limiting the number of elements to exactly five.

Comment: Trying to figure out what you mean, but the source of the bloat is unclear to me. You basically have three options to avoid code repetition/bloat in fluid. The ForViewHelper for loops, sections for code in the same file, partials for outsourcing. Using the controller to prepare a data structure you can then easily iterate through would be another option.

Comment: Btw, reading the question again, the values "as" and "key" will be assigned to variables. I see no reason, why label="Angebot Tag {number}" or name="angebot{number}" shouldn't work. The ForViewHelper, btw, already has an iteration="variablename" attribute which assigns an Iterator object, that has a cycle property, that does state the current index.

Comment: Your last comment was the right push to the answer, thank you! The for-loop was working just correctly, but I tried adding multiple fields with the same name which will be prevented by TYPO3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to j4k3's last comment on my question I found out what I was doing wrong: I was trying to apply multiple fields with the same name which isn't allowed. This code using the 'key' works (could also use iteration):

```
<f:for each="{0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4}" as="foo" key="number">
          <flux:field.multiRelation label="Angebot Tag {number}" name="offerDay{number}" table="tx_data_domain_model_offer">
          </flux:field.multiRelation>
</f:for>
```